# Как отловить параметры Get вида index.php?do=somethink в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

Как отловить параметры Get вида `index.php?do=somethink` в Laravel.
Гугл выдает подобного вида страницы хотя их нет уже несколько лет еще до перехода на Laravel была такая маршрутизация, хотелось бы подобные страницы отдавать с кодом 404. Какие варианты есть отлова. Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правильно понял - все запросы с get параметрами должны отправляться на 404, тогда такое решение:

В /app/Exceptions/Handler.php, допиши метод render()

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
     $query = $request->query(); // возвращает get параметры
     if (!empty($query)) { 
          // тут уже $query проверяй как тебе удобно, в методе написано что он может вернуть как массив, так и строку,  
          return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);

         /** дальше весь остальной код**/

     }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал тишина, Exception вроде как возникает после какого то события, которое ловим, а при строке с параметрами эксепшна не происходит, из за этого не ловит, то есть параметры надо гдето в другом месте ловить например в самом файле index.php

Comment: Решил отловом в router файле, в эксепшене ловить смысла нет так как самого эксепшена не возникает

Comment: @АнтонВеселов а причем тут Exception? в момент рендеринга мы просто проверяем запрос `$request` на наличие GET параметров и если они есть, показываем 404

Answer (score -1):

Объявите:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;    

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');

    //
}
```